# Home screen shortcut app no installed

Tags: java, android

I find out code that create a shortcut on home screen it works but when I click it on home screen it say : App no installed . Some help?

**My code :**

```
        Intent shortcutIntent;
    shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), ".GetQuoteActivity"));

    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    final Intent putShortCutIntent = new Intent();
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,
            shortcutIntent);

    // Sets the custom shortcut's title
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,  "Get Quote");
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
            GetQuoteActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    putShortCutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(putShortCutIntent);
}
```

**AndroidManifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.files.getquote"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

      <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"></uses-permission>

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity 
            android:name=".GetQuoteActivity" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possibilities:

1. Change to this:

   ```
   shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
       getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), GetQuoteActivity.class));
   ```
2. Use this code to create the shortcut:

   ```
   Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent (this, YourActivity.class);      
   Intent addIntent = new Intent(); 
   addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
   addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Title"); 
   addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); 
   addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon)); 

   sendBroadcast(addIntent);
   ```

Comment: Absolutely perfect i would like to give you up but dont have enough requires. So only mark as done. :)

Comment: And 1 more question when i click on the app more time it always show shortcut app name created it is possible to show only 1 time ?

Comment: app not installed, how to fix that ?